# Laptop Series Battery Compatability

Tags: laptop, battery

I need to replace my Toshiba Satellite L655-13X battery with a new one. The batteries I found are for L655-S5083, and L655-S5150. They appear to be the same in the picture to my battery. However, how can I confirm? The description doesn't say anything about compatibility with other models.

So my question is: how to know if all Toshiba Satellite L655-* are the same in terms of battery physical structure?

I understand that I need to have the exact same voltage. More mAh and/or Wh is better. The problem is with the size.

Comment: Make it a 'condition of sale' that it _must_ fit. If the sales rep quibbles, that's a red flag. Also, see https://www.batteriesplus.com/battery/laptop/toshiba/satellite-l655-series

Answer (score 1):

Contact a sales rep at Batteries Plus which has a [very detailed set of choices](https://www.batteriesplus.com/battery/laptop/toshiba/satellite-l655-series) for Toshiba L655 series batteries. Make it a 'condition of sale' that it must fit. If the sales rep quibbles or won't agree to the stipulation, that's a red flag, because it guarantees your bank or credit card company *will* chargeback against them if it doesn't work or fit. Vendors *hate* chargebacks.

Also, two websites were found which show compatibility (thanks to the OP!):

https://www.irelandbattery.com/toshiba-batteries/toshiba-satellite-l655-13x-battery.htm

https://www.laptopbattery.com.sg/toshiba/toshiba-satellite-l655-13x-batteries.htm

Comment: I came across these two sites that list compatible batteries model/parth numbers: https://www.irelandbattery.com/toshiba-batteries/toshiba-satellite-l655-13x-battery.htm, https://www.laptopbattery.com.sg/toshiba/toshiba-satellite-l655-13x-batteries.htm

Comment: I will save those for future use. TY!